# Dlib install error in pip process in streamlit application

Tags: python-3.x, pip, streamlit, dlib

I developed the streamlit application which is working fine in my Windows 10 local PC but when i tried to deploy the application in streamlit community cloud, the pip installation failed on dlib compilation step

Here is my requirements.txt file

```
streamlit
opencv-python
dlib
numpy
```

Here is my packages.txt file to install apt packages I think required for dlib

```
libopenblas-dev
liblapack-dev
libboost-all-dev
```

And here is the log content I copied from the log section of Streamlit app deployment process.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [284 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      Building extension for Python 3.8.18 (default, Sep  7 2023, 13:47:34)
      Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake /tmp/pip-install-pu4jgcso/dlib_e82238ea87cf482baa325cc108ea99d7/tools/python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/tmp/pip-install-pu4jgcso/dlib_e82238ea87cf482baa325cc108ea99d7/build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/adminuser/venv/bin/python -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'
      -- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1
      -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      CMake Deprecation Warning at /tmp/pip-install-pu4jgcso/dlib_e82238ea87cf482baa325cc108ea99d7/dlib/external/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:8 (cmake_minimum_required):
        Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
        CMake.
      
        Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
        CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
      
      
      -- pybind11 v2.10.0
      CMake Warning (dev) at /tmp/pip-install-pu4jgcso/dlib_e82238ea87cf482baa325cc108ea99d7/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:98 (find_package):
        Policy CMP0148 is not set: The FindPythonInterp and FindPythonLibs modules
        are removed.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0148" for policy details.  Use
        the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
      
      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        /tmp/pip-install-pu4jgcso/dlib_e82238ea87cf482baa325cc108ea99d7/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:50 (find_package)
        /tmp/pip-install-pu4jgcso/dlib_e82238ea87cf482baa325cc108ea99d7/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/pybind11Common.cmake:180 (include)
        /tmp/pip-install-pu4jgcso/dlib_e82238ea87cf482baa325cc108ea99d7/dlib/external/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:200 (include)
      This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
      
      -- Found PythonInterp: /home/adminuser/venv/bin/python (found suitable version "3.8.18", minimum required is "3.6")
      -- Found PythonLibs: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.8.so
      -- Performing Test HAS_FLTO
      -- Performing Test HAS_FLTO - Success
      -- Using CMake version: 3.27.4
      -- Compiling dlib version: 19.24.2
      -- SSE4 instructions can be executed by the host processor.
      -- AVX instructions can be executed by the host processor.
      -- Enabling AVX instructions
      -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
      -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
      -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
      -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
      -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
      -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
      -- Found Threads: TRUE
      -- Could NOT find X11 (missing: X11_X11_INCLUDE_PATH X11_X11_LIB)
       *****************************************************************************
       *** DLIB GUI SUPPORT DISABLED BECAUSE X11 DEVELOPMENT LIBRARIES NOT FOUND ***
       *** Make sure libx11-dev is installed if you want GUI support.            ***
       *** On Ubuntu run: sudo apt-get install libx11-dev                        ***
       *****************************************************************************
      -- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
      -- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
      -- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
      -- Looking for cblas_ddot
      -- Looking for cblas_ddot - not found
      -- Looking for sys/types.h
      -- Looking for sys/types.h - found
      -- Looking for stdint.h
      -- Looking for stdint.h - found
      -- Looking for stddef.h
      -- Looking for stddef.h - found
      -- Check size of void*
      -- Check size of void* - done
      -- Found OpenBLAS library
      -- Looking for sgetrf_single
      -- Looking for sgetrf_single - found
      -- Using OpenBLAS's built in LAPACK
      -- Looking for cblas_ddot
      -- Looking for cblas_ddot - found
      -- Looking for sgesv
      -- Looking for sgesv - not found
      -- Looking for sgesv_
      -- Looking for sgesv_ - not found
      CMake Warning (dev) at /tmp/pip-install-pu4jgcso/dlib_e82238ea87cf482baa325cc108ea99d7/dlib/CMakeLists.txt:628 (find_package):
        Policy CMP0146 is not set: The FindCUDA module is removed.  Run "cmake
        --help-policy CMP0146" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
        set the policy and suppress this warning.
      
      This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
      
      CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
      -- Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "7.5")
      -- Found CUDA, but CMake was unable to find the cuBLAS libraries that should be part of every basic CUDA install. Your CUDA install is somehow broken or incomplete. Since cuBLAS is required for dlib to use CUDA we won't use CUDA.
      -- DID NOT FIND CUDA
      -- Disabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL NOT USE CUDA
      -- Searching for FFMPEG/LIBAV
      -- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
      -- PkgConfig could not be found, FFMPEG won't be available
      -- Configuring done (2.3s)
      -- Generating done (0.0s)
      -- Build files have been written to: /tmp/pip-install-pu4jgcso/dlib_e82238ea87cf482baa325cc108ea99d7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      Invoking CMake build: 'cmake --build . --config Release -- -j16'
      [  1%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bigint/bigint_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [  1%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [  3%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bigint/bigint_kernel_2.cpp.o
      [  3%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bit_stream/bit_stream_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [  4%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_2.cpp.o
      [  4%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [  5%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_encoder/entropy_encoder_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [  5%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_encoder/entropy_encoder_kernel_2.cpp.o
      [  6%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/unicode/unicode.cpp.o
      [  7%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/md5/md5_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [  7%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/tokenizer/tokenizer_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [  8%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/test_for_odr_violations.cpp.o
      [  8%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/fft/fft.cpp.o
      [  9%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [  9%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [ 10%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bsp/bsp.cpp.o
      [ 11%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_kernel_2.cpp.o
      [ 12%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_extensions.cpp.o
      [ 12%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/fonts.cpp.o
      [ 13%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/linker/linker_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [ 13%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/extra_logger_headers.cpp.o
      [ 14%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/logger_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [ 15%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/logger_config_file.cpp.o
      [ 15%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/misc_api/misc_api_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [ 16%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/misc_api/misc_api_kernel_2.cpp.o
      [ 17%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_extensions.cpp.o
      [ 17%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_kernel_2.cpp.o
      [ 18%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockstreambuf/sockstreambuf.cpp.o
      [ 19%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockstreambuf/sockstreambuf_unbuffered.cpp.o
      [ 19%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_kernel.cpp.o
      [ 20%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_iostream.cpp.o
      [ 20%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_http.cpp.o
      [ 21%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/multithreaded_object_extension.cpp.o
      [ 22%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threaded_object_extension.cpp.o
      [ 22%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_1.cpp.o
      [ 23%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_2.cpp.o
      [ 24%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_shared.cpp.o
      [ 24%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/thread_pool_extension.cpp.o
      [ 25%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/async.cpp.o
      [ 26%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/timer/timer.cpp.o
      [ 26%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/stack_trace.cpp.o
      [ 27%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/cuda/cpu_dlib.cpp.o
      [ 27%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/cuda/tensor_tools.cpp.o
      [ 28%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/data_io/image_dataset_metadata.cpp.o
      [ 29%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/data_io/mnist.cpp.o
      [ 29%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/data_io/cifar.cpp.o
      [ 30%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/global_optimization/global_function_search.cpp.o
      [ 31%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/filtering/kalman_filter.cpp.o
      [ 31%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/svm/auto.cpp.o
      [ 32%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/arm/arm_init.c.o
      [ 33%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/arm/filter_neon_intrinsics.c.o
      [ 33%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/arm/palette_neon_intrinsics.c.o
      [ 34%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/png.c.o
      [ 34%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngerror.c.o
      [ 35%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngget.c.o
      [ 36%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngmem.c.o
      [ 36%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngpread.c.o
      [ 37%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngread.c.o
      [ 38%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngrio.c.o
      [ 38%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngrtran.c.o
      [ 39%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngrutil.c.o
      [ 40%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngset.c.o
      [ 40%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngtrans.c.o
      [ 41%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngwio.c.o
      [ 41%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngwrite.c.o
      [ 42%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngwtran.c.o
      [ 43%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libpng/pngwutil.c.o
      [ 43%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/adler32.c.o
      [ 44%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/compress.c.o
      [ 44%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/deflate.c.o
      [ 45%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/crc32.c.o
      [ 46%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/gzclose.c.o
      [ 47%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/gzlib.c.o
      [ 47%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/gzread.c.o
      [ 48%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/gzwrite.c.o
      [ 48%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/infback.c.o
      [ 49%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/inffast.c.o
      [ 50%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/inflate.c.o
      [ 50%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/inftrees.c.o
      [ 51%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/trees.c.o
      [ 52%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/uncompr.c.o
      [ 52%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/zlib/zutil.c.o
      [ 53%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_loader/png_loader.cpp.o
      [ 54%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_saver/save_png.cpp.o
      [ 54%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jaricom.c.o
      [ 55%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcapimin.c.o
      [ 55%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcapistd.c.o
      [ 56%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcarith.c.o
      [ 57%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jccoefct.c.o
      [ 57%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jccolor.c.o
      [ 58%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcdctmgr.c.o
      [ 59%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jchuff.c.o
      [ 60%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcmainct.c.o
      [ 60%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcinit.c.o
      [ 61%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcmarker.c.o
      [ 61%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcmaster.c.o
      [ 62%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcomapi.c.o
      [ 62%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcparam.c.o
      [ 63%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcprepct.c.o
      [ 64%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jcsample.c.o
      [ 64%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdapimin.c.o
      [ 65%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdapistd.c.o
      [ 66%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdarith.c.o
      [ 66%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdatadst.c.o
      [ 67%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdcoefct.c.o
      [ 68%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdatasrc.c.o
      [ 68%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdcolor.c.o
      [ 69%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jddctmgr.c.o
      [ 69%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdhuff.c.o
      [ 70%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdinput.c.o
      [ 71%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmainct.c.o
      [ 71%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmarker.c.o
      [ 72%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmaster.c.o
      [ 73%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdmerge.c.o
      [ 73%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdpostct.c.o
      [ 74%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jdsample.c.o
      [ 75%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jerror.c.o
      [ 75%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jfdctflt.c.o
      [ 76%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jfdctfst.c.o
      [ 76%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jfdctint.c.o
      [ 77%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jidctflt.c.o
      [ 78%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jidctfst.c.o
      [ 79%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jmemmgr.c.o
      [ 79%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jidctint.c.o
      [ 80%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jmemnobs.c.o
      [ 80%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jquant1.c.o
      [ 81%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jutils.c.o
      [ 82%] Building C object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/external/libjpeg/jquant2.c.o
      [ 82%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_loader/jpeg_loader.cpp.o
      [ 83%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_saver/save_jpeg.cpp.o
      c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
      compilation terminated.
      gmake[2]: *** [dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/build.make:650: dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/cuda/cpu_dlib.cpp.o] Error 1
      gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
      gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:144: dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/all] Error 2
      gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_p41pcjd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 434, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_p41pcjd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 419, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_p41pcjd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 218, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_p41pcjd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_p41pcjd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_p41pcjd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_p41pcjd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_p41pcjd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_p41pcjd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_p41pcjd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 364, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_p41pcjd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_p41pcjd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_p41pcjd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_p41pcjd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_p41pcjd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_p41pcjd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_p41pcjd/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "<string>", line 130, in run
        File "<string>", line 170, in build_extension
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '-j16']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.3; however, version 23.2.1 is available.
```

I am not able to understand what is going wrong during dlib installation.

Comment: It looks like `dlib` is installable in Community Cloud via `conda` but not `pip` – adding the package via an `environment.yml` file should work https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/dlib-cmake-build-error-in-deployment-to-streamlit-sharing/10140/3

Comment: Wow @CarolineFrasca this resolved my problem, kindly add your comment as an answer i will mark it accepted for others as this issue is not widely explained in streamlit itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `dlib` is installable in Community Cloud via `conda` but not `pip` – adding the package via an `environment.yml` file should work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, `pip install face_recognition` which install `dlib` just stop without an obvious error message, pip was running out of memory, it require a lot of RAM to build, 10GB is not enough, i had to increase my VM ram and SWAP for pip to build wihout problem.

The weird part i can build `dlib` from source with `cmake` without any RAM problem

Comment: but in streamlit you have only 1Gb of RAM available for you to perform whatever processing your code requires